# Can't get Tkinter GUI to show using classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a Tkinter GUI that takes Excel documents, reads them, and exports them to the window. The issue is when I changed the code to below to incorporate class structure, I cannot make the GUI load properly anymore.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def NewFile():
    print("New File!")
def OpenFile():
    name = askopenfilename()
    print(name)
def About():
    print("About works")
def deletelist():
    listbox.delete(0, END)

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        self.load = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Load XLSX File", command = OpenFile)
        self.load.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')

        self.ckframe = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="Currency Selections")
        self.ckframe.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, stick = 'nesw')
        self.prochk = tk.Checkbutton(self.ckframe, text = '1 Currency').grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w')
        self.msnchk = tk.Checkbutton(self.ckframe, text = '2 Currency').grid(row = 1, column = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w')
        self.nightschk = tk.Checkbutton(self.ckframe, text = '3 Currency').grid(row = 1, column = 4, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w')
        self.semichk = tk.Checkbutton(self.ckframe, text = '4 Currency').grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w')
        self.instqualCRchk = tk.Checkbutton(self.ckframe, text = '5 Currency').grid(row = 2, column = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w')
        self.msnCRchk = tk.Checkbutton(self.ckframe, text = '6 Currency').grid(row = 2, column = 4, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w')

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.frame, width = 83)
        self.listbox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = 'w') # Fix width size function
        self.listbox.insert(1, 'Test1')
        self.listbox.insert(0, 'Test2')
        self.save = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Save").grid(row = 8, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, stick = 'e')
        self.delete = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Delete", command = deletelist).grid(row = 8, column = 0, padx = 45, pady = 5, stick = 'e')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I searched a lot trying to find a solution to using classes with tkinter GUI and the grid system but I mostly found ways to make GUIs with pack() solution.

Comment: Read [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759) and [Best way to structure a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl: neither of those links are relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of `MainApplication` is a frame. You never call `pack` or `place` or `grid` on that instance so that frame and all of its children will be invisible.

This frame creates another frame that contains all of the other widgets, `self.frame`. You never call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on it either, so it and all of its children will be invisible.

Since the widgets are in a frame that is invisible, and that frame itself is invisible, none of the other widgets will be visible.

The first thing to do is to get rid of `self.frame`. Remove the line that creates it, and everywhere you reference `self.frame`, replace it with `self`.  Since `self` in this context is already a frame it makes no sense to create another frame inside.

Next, you need to add the instance of `MainApplication` to the window. Since it's the only widget directly in the root window, `pack` is the simplest choice.

```
root = tk.Tk()
app = = MainApplication(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: That works but messes up the formatting a little bit. I did find that I never defined the frame in `MainApplication` so I added `self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')` under `self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)` and that worked as well. How will this effect my program overall compared to using `pack()`?

Comment: @MicahRutherford: as long as you remember to call `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` to assign weights appropriately, `grid` will work just as well as `pack`. However, if `self.frame` has `self.master` as it's parent, it defeats the purpose of `MainApplication` inheriting from `Frame`. It's a bad practice for a class like this to put widgets in the parent rather than in itself. It destroys encapsulation.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies! Makes sense and the program works perfect now after a little tweaking with the rows and columns in the widgets. Actually works better now.